# How to change the return key of UIKeyboard with customized button for iPhone using MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, uikeyboard, uikeyboardtype

I need to add a button to `UIKeyboard` in the place of Return key and also need to raise events for that customized button for iPhone using MonoTouch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the UITextInputTraits protocol. It defines a returnKeyType (UIReturnKeyType) which can be

```
typedef enum {
   UIReturnKeyDefault,
   UIReturnKeyGo,
   UIReturnKeyGoogle,
   UIReturnKeyJoin,
   UIReturnKeyNext,
   UIReturnKeyRoute,
   UIReturnKeySearch,
   UIReturnKeySend,
   UIReturnKeyYahoo,
   UIReturnKeyDone,
   UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
} UIReturnKeyType;
```

The UITextField and UITextView classes support this protocol. I don't think you can customize it further unless you do some very hacky stuff.

If you have a UITextField then you can implement

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

and if you have a UITextView you can implement

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

both delegate methods, to determine the behaviour on return.

Comment: Sorry,I need to set as Login, How?or else , is there any possible to set an image to that Return key?

Comment: Probably UIReturnKeyGo or UIReturnKeyJoin would be your best bet, looking up keyboard customization, doesn't seem to be possible to set an image.

Comment: But, client requires that return key as "Login" and "Do" and some their own names.I should do as they gave.I saw in some apps, they did as their own button.

Comment: It's not possible to changes keys using the **public** API provided by Apple. There's quite a few questions on stackoverflow if you want more details.

Comment: But,i saw in many apps.In facebook app also we get Login instead of return.

Comment: Hello Kishore, did u solve this problem? i'm in the same problem like you

Comment: But...this answer has nothing to do with Monotouch, as stipulated in the question.

Answer (score -4):

You could add a UIButton on the superview in the same postion of the keyboard button.

Comment: wow.. please don't do this. I would suggest you write your own keyboard before doing this